# natbib: combining chicago style and sorting by appearance

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

I would like my citations to be formatted according to the Chicago style, and at the same time numbered by order of appearance.

The `sort&compress` option does work as expected using `unsrt` bibliography style, with citations numbered by order of appearance. However, they get automatically sorted alphabetically as soon as I replace `unsrt` with `chicago` for the bibliography style:

```
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}

... document...

\bibliographystyle{chicago}


\bibliography{main}
```

Is it possible to get citations styled according to `chicago` but sorted according to `unsrt` (that is, by order of appearance)?

Comment: Is it the *citations* or the *entries in the references section* that you want to get styled a la `chicago`? Please advise.

Comment: I want the entries in the references section to get styled a la chicago, but sorted in a numbered list according to their order of appearance. In the main text I do get the citations to appear as numbers into square brackets, as desired.

Answer (score 5):

Good news: You need to make only two small changes to the file `chicago.bst` to suppress the alphabetical sorting of the referenced items and, instead, to get them listed in the order they are first cited in the document.

- Find the file `chicago.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy of this file. Name the copy, say, `mychicago.bst`. (Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `mychicago.bst` in your favorite text editor; the editor you use to edit your TeX files will do fine.
- Locate the two lines that start with `SORT` -- uppercase is important. In the copy of `chicago.bst` I found in my TeX distribution, the two lines in question are numbered 1565 and 1629.
- Comment out these two lines, e.g., by inserting a `%` sign at the start of each of the two lines.
- Save the file `mychicago.bst`, either to the directory that contains your main `.tex` file or to a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the TeX filename database in a way that's appropriate for your TeX distribution. If you don't understand the preceding sentence, you should probably go with the first option.
- Start using the new bibliography style file by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` with `\bibliographystyle{mychicago}`.
- As always after changing the bibliography style, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on your document in order to fully propagate all changes.

The following example illustrates the effects of making use of the unsorted "chicago" style. Observe that while the three test entries are sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames in the bib file, they are sorted by the order of first citation in the formatted bibliopgraphy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{filecontents} % update Apr 2024: not needed anymore

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{aa,
  author = "A. Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Various Communications",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 1,
  issue  = 1,
  pages  = "1-10",
}
@article{bb,
  author = "B. Buthor",
  title  = "Further thoughts",
  journal= "Various Communications",
  year   = 3002,
  volume = 2,
  issue  = 1,
  pages  = "11-20",
}
@article{cc,
  author = "C. Cuthor",
  title  = "Still more thoughts",
  journal= "Various Communications",
  year   = 3003,
  volume = 3,
  issue  = 1,
  pages  = "21-30",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}  % <-- nuneric-style citation call-outs
\bibliographystyle{mychicago} % <-- new bib style is in use

\begin{document}
\cite{cc}, \cite{bb}, \cite{aa}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```