# How to order bibliography as references appear in the document using IEEE format

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, ieee-style

Can anyone tell me what is the default ordering when using the `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` format for the references in a LaTeX document?

As far as I am aware, I am using the default of the format.

Comment: The entries shown in the bibliography section are sorted alphabetically by author(s) and numerically by year.

Comment: So if I have a reference with several authors, they will be sorted alphabetically, but I find that the references are not being ordered numerically by year. I have one dates 2006 before one for 2003, for example.

Comment: No: *Within* a given entry, no sorting is done: The authors will be listed exactly in the order they're listed in the `author` field. Sorting refers to an operation *across* entries, not within an entry.

Comment: It there any option to order the references by the order in which they appear in the document? So that the first \cite{XXX} in the document will be the first in the bibliography?

Comment: Check out the posting [natbib: combining chicago style and sorting by appearance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162127/5001). The posting is about the `chicago` bibliography style, but the method described in the answer to that query applies to the `ieeetr` bibliography style as well. (Of course, you should edit a copy of `ieeetr.bst` rather than of `chicago.bst`.a0

Comment: @MrMorgan that's the default I think, if you use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.  The various options are described in the `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf` documentation.

Comment: I find no lines headed `SORT` in `ieeetr.bst` based upon `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162127/natbib-combining-chicago-style-and-sorting-by-appearance`. And using `\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bibliography.bib} \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} \label{ch:Bibliography}` to generate the bibliography still produces a list which is not in the order I want, i.e. as they appear in the document. So where am I wrong?

Comment: After changing the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction from `ieeetr` to `IEEEtran`, did you remember to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes?

Comment: Yes. I am using WinEdt 9 with MikTeX 2.9. So the re-running tends to be automated. But even running the document twice manually with `\bibliography{Bibliography} \bibliographystyle{ieeetran} \label{ch:Bibliography}` and no edits made to `.bst` files, the references are not in order of appearance in the document. So what am I not doing or doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` not `\usepackage{ieeetran}`

Comment: I've done this but what order does `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` put the references in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this:

```
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\label{ch:Bibliography}
```

And the references are now in alphabetical order which is acceptable.