# Maintain the agsm style while keeping the bibliography unsorted

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using `natbib`, I would like to have the bibliography in the order that it is in the file while using the `agsm` bibliography style.

This is only currently possible when using the `unsrt` style because I am using the `\nocite{*}` command to ensure that all items in the bibliography are displayed, since I am required to have a bibliography and a references page, however the `multibib` package seems to be the only way this can be done, instead I will use the bibliography to display the references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is virtually identical to the one recommended for the `chicago` bibliography style. See [natbib: combining chicago style and sorting by appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162127/5001) and the [associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162180/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!].

- Locate the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution.
- Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `agsm-unsrt.bst`.
- Open the file `agsm-unsrt.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, locate the instances of `SORT` on lines 1296 and 1329. Either comment them out or delete them.
- Save the bst file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In the main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsm-unsrt}`. Be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully update the formatted bibliography and all citation call-outs.

Happy BibTeXing!